# nested array typescript type

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
    type FixedArray<T, D extends number> = Array<T> & {
        length: D
    }

    type NestedArrays<T> = Array<T | NestedArrays<T>>

type FixedArray<T, D extends number> = Array<T> & {
    length: D
}

const a: FixedArray<FixedArray<FixedArray<number, 2>, 2>, 3> = [
    [
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2],
    ],
    [
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2],
    ],
    [
        [1, 2],
        [1, 2],
    ],
]
```

I've never been able to get the array length to be automatically inferred from the child elements

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do the kind of inference you're looking for without using a function. The function doesn't have to *do* anything, it's just there so you can do the inference. In this case, you could do it like this:

```typescript
function fixed<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]>(
    ...elements: ArrayType
): FixedArray<ArrayType[number], ArrayType["length"]> {
    return elements;
}
```

Then using it for your example is:

```
const a = fixed(
    fixed(
        fixed(1, 2),
        fixed(1, 2)
    ),
    fixed(
        fixed(1, 2),
        fixed(1, 2)
    ),
    fixed(
        fixed(1, 2),
        fixed(1, 2)
    ),
);

console.log(a);
//          ^? - const a: FixedArray<FixedArray<FixedArray<number, 2>, 2>, 3>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgDwgEwIICd0EMQB4AqANFACJQQLAQB2yAzlNQK4C2ARhOgHxQC8U6CFmQB7agBsQUfAG0AulABkUAN4AoKJqjiaAc2AALAFykA3GoC+5tQDMm1AMbA4YqDcQpcGbCHzhoFFS0DILCYpJQ9gDW1CIA7tTyXAAUGloAdJkQOiw0wHQm3jh+kGoAlCbwSGiYOF61vv4yzOyccsRFjZAyAEQ61PoGPXI86loCEMBM6NTkOXl05hZqag5idMBQWHxuHsip4+7VB+NaRyjJAIzEAExlhGmnu8fXUHePUPcf5-sfh3tXW5fJ6aH6At5lD7As4Av4wl5Ah4g54XV7vcZfMrWNbUOgiHTpcQiXTJLBYtQAegpyM0AD0APxAA)

---

FWIW, you don't need your own `FixedArray` type if you don't want it, you can just use readonly tuples:

```typescript
function fixed<ArrayType extends readonly unknown[]>(
    ...elements: ArrayType
): Readonly<ArrayType> {
    return elements;
}
```

Same usage; the resulting type is

```
readonly [
    readonly [
        readonly [number, number],
        readonly [number, number]
    ],
    readonly [
        readonly [number, number],
        readonly [number, number]
    ],
    readonly [
        readonly [number, number],
        readonly [number, number]
    ]
]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglgDwgEwIICd0EMQB4AqANFACJQQLAQB2yAzlNQK4C2ARhOgHxQC8U6CFmQB7agBsQUfAG0AulABkUAN4AoKJqjiaAc2AALAFykA3GoC+5tQDMm1AMbA4YqDcQpcGbCHzhoFFS0DILCYpJQ9gDW1CIA7tTyXAAUGloAdJkQOiw0wHQm3jh+kGoAlCYASkKiEnhFvv486loCEMBM6NTkOXl05hZqag5idMBQWHxuHsipre5Is2mtmgsoyQCMxABMZYTLK2uzW1C7B3sHR3MrqzObOxc3t4v3p2Xn+-N3B18vJ7ufJ5Xf7vVoXMrWEbUOgiHTpcQiXTJLAQtQAejRTy0AD0APxqIA)